# Firebase push web notifications for anonymous users

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, web-notifications, anonymous-users

Is it possible to push web notification in Firebase for anonymous users with using just the UID because there will be no tokens for anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase authentication UID are not related to the tokens you get from the WebPush subscription.

That means you can subscribe any kind of user with webpush as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/how-push-works), and don't even think about firebase authentication.

Comment: okey what about the guests, or the anonymous users ? is it possible to push a notifications to their devices ? even they are not surfing the website the time the notification pushed ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You only need the permission from the browser and then you can send notifications to them. I can recommend to do this codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/push-notifications/#0 - it covers the subscription process and sending the push notification.

Comment: even the browser is closed ?

Comment: No. If the browser is really closed, the notification can't be received and is queue in the push service until it can be delivered or the message expired. See details here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/faq, section "Why doesn't push work when the browser is closed?"